# html before change background in one page in project using sass

Tags: html, sass, pseudo-element

On my wordpress website I am using sass to generate CSS ¨

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    background: $primary;
    display: block;
    height: 384px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

I need to change the background of this block but only on one page. Is this possible with sass or how can I change background-color on one page only, or is any way to disable his before pseudo-element on one page?

Comment: Can't you set this on the ```body``` instead and target it that way with classes?

Comment: You think add this code for pseudoelement before add to body tag?

Comment: Yes, try it on the ```body``` tag.

Comment: Yes, this solve my problem. I move from html to `body`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some part of the code, you can write this code in a script tag, maybe it can help

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";
```